# Is it possible to rename your characters after starting a game?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I recently started a new game and actually spent a decent amount of time building my characters instead of using the pre-built stuff. However, I completely forgot to give them names so now everybody is named something like "New Character". Of course, this isn't game-breaking in the least but it's annoying (and makes me feel a tad stupid).

Is there any way of changing your character's names after you've started the game (either officially or through some amount of moderate hackery)?

Comment: Ahhh, "New Character"...the pride of *[subject hometown here]*

Comment: "moderate hackery" - does using a binary diff tool (to figure out where to edit) and hex editor (to do the edits) count as "moderate" in your book?  I'm thinking that if your save is anything beyond having *just* started it might become much more difficult.  File offsets could be disturbed if you change string lengths - if the save file has any of those, and doesn't pad out names to their max length.  But you could get lucky.

Comment: Never mind, went and opened it and didn't see the character names anywhere in the file in plaintext.  It's gonna take a custom program to change them.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham well buggers, I was worried that might be the case

Comment: As far as roguelike character names go, "New Character" is pretty decent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enable the in-game Lua console, you can use it to rename a character on the fly.

To enable the console, you need to edit your `grimrock.cfg` file, which can be found in the same place as your saved games. (You should close Grimrock before doing this.) The file is broken up into sections; in the first section, there's a line with `console = false`. Just change the `false` to `true`.

You probably also want to change the `consoleKey` line, since the default is a key that doesn't exist on an American keyboard (I believe it's the § key on a Finnish keyboard, but I'm not certain of that). I recommend using a function key, since whichever key you choose overrides anything else you might want to do in the console (for example, if you choose Z as the key, you cannot type a Z in the console). To use F12, change the `consoleKey` line to read `consoleKey = 123`.

Once you have the console enabled, you just have to type the following command in to change a character's name:

```
party:getChampion(2):setName("New Name")
```

Where you replace 2 with the champion to change (in the range 1 to 4) and New Name with whatever name you choose.

If you want to disable the console again afterwards (since it could be a temptation to cheat in all sorts of ways!), you can just change `grimrock.cfg` back to `console = false`.

Answer (score 2):

According to discussion on [Grimrock.net](http://www.grimrock.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2225) and a couple of other websites I found, it doesn't appear that there's yet any *official* way to rename characters after you start the game. There are quite a few people complaining about it as a missing feature.

However, one of the forum members created a [python script that claims to do that](http://www.grimrock.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=1055&p=24115#p24115). At the moment there is only a single reply (saying 'good job', so that's positive) but it was only posted little over a week ago. I have not tested, verified or otherwise examined this script so **use it at your own risk**.

And, of course, back up your save before you try anything!